# After starting an application for the second time, the splash image does not disappear

Tags: xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Worklight v5.0.5 and have created a Worklight Hybrid application; I am running the app on iOS v5.1.1, compiled with Xcode 4.6.

When I execute the application in the iPad from Xcode - the iPad connected with the USB cable to the Mac - the application starts fine, I see the splash screen and then the login page.

If I disconnect the USB cable I'm not able to run the application again. Once I kill the application from the iPad, or stopping it ib Xcode before disconnecting the USB cable, I'm not able to start it again, the application does not go past the splash image.

Similarly, if I generate an .ipa and I install the it via the IBM Worklight Application Center then the first time I start the application it is fine, but if I kill the application (click twice the home button and so on...) then the next time I start the application it won't go past the splash image as well.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed similar behavior, not the same scenarios as you have described. For me, this helped:

After disconnecting the device from the Mac, I have made sure to exit the app in the same manner you have and to also close the iPad (not shut down, just clicking the power button to close the display) and then try to run the app again. You can also try shutting down the iPad. If that helps, this is not a Worklight issue...

---

Based on comment #3 to this answer, which revealed the issue at hand:

Once creating an application - for example with the name "newApp". this value, "newApp" is referenced in several locations throughout the project - the HTML filename, in application-descriptor.xml, references to the CSS and JS files of the applications and possibly another one or two references.

Changing this value is **not supported**. Changing it can indeed cause what is described in this question, and other oddities. Revert the change, and the application will work.

Comment: Hi. No way. I have tried closing the iPad and also shutting down, but the application does no start again.
If it is not Worklight, is it my fault? Do I have to do something in XCode?

Comment: I have tested this with iPhone 4S running iOS 6.1.3, with an app created using Worklight 5.0.6.1 and built using Xcode 4.6, and could not reproduce.

Comment: I got it!!! The problem is to change the <mainFile> in the application-descriptor.xml (and also the html file name). You must use as mainFile name the same as the application, you can not change it. Now that I know how to reproduce I will ask official support. Thank you Idan.